# Multiple output of neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution, object-detection

I am trying to wrap my head around multiple output of neural networks, especially output of CNN in image classification with localization:

Lets say we have CNN with 2 cond layers (conv + pool, conv + pool) and 2 fully-connected (FC) layers. At the end, the last FC layer is connected to softmax layer. The softmax layer will output vector of probabilities of classes (let's say we have 4: dog, cat, car, something else). Now my question is, **what is the way to retrieve the location of detected object?** I mean the vector $(x,y,width,height)$?

If I understand it correctly, I map another layer to the last FC layer (so the last FC layer is connected to softmax layer, and this layer). However how does it outputs the vector I need? I am really confused about this.

Answer (score 1):

Object classification is something *very different* from object detection/localization. I recommend you having a look at some papers that do object detection using neural networks. The prominent examples are:

- [Faster RCNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497)
- [Single Shot multibox Detector](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325)
- [YOLO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640)

All of these networks have publicly available implementations in various neural network frameworks and there are also many blogs explaining them in detail.

Comment: could you please link some blog? All i have found about yolo for example was just few words how it circa works.

Comment: How about [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-ssd-multibox-real-time-object-detection-in-deep-learning-495ef744fab)?